# jQuery move list item to end of list

Tags: jquery, list, traversal

I have this list that can be sorted with sortable.
How can I move the li item with class .neutral to the end of the list when sorting is finished?

```
$(".thumbs").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        // move .neutral at the end of this list
    }
});

<ul class="thumbs">
    <li>red</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li class="neutral">none</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>blue</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can append (moving) them to the end of the list with [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
$(".thumbs").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).find('.neutral').appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/APe3B/1/), this gets all the `.neutral` elements inside and appends them to `this` which is the `ul.thumbs` we're currently in, this will work for multiple independent lists of thumbnails too.

Comment: hi Nick. Actually I am trying something with droppable and sortable already so that doesn't do it for me.. Could you have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Y2ER7/ It's based on jquery.ui.droppable shopping-cart example. (I need to find a way to get the src from the thumbs as well btw)

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent would be the following:

```
$(".neutral").appendTo(".thumbs");
OR
$(".thumbs").append(".neutral");
```

You can move an element around a page by selecting it and appending or prepending it elsewhere.

NB: be careful with scope - if you're using classes and this UI appears multiple times on a page the above selctors will need to be scoped to the current instance using the `ui` parameter passed into the stop function.